# How to display error when no file selected

Tags: asp.net, image, error-handling

Our classic ASP application uses one .aspx page to upload an image for each client.
I'm not familiar with ASP.net, so this page is difficult for me to understand.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="VB" RunAt="Server">

        Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Span1.InnerHtml = "You may not upload a file larger than 250 Kilobytes. Your image must be in JPG format.<br />Please crop your image to 400 pixels high and 300 pixels wide, so that no distortion will occur when displayed.<br /><br />"
        End Sub

        Sub Upload_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Dim DistributorID As Integer
            DistributorID = request.QueryString("distID")

            ' Display properties of the uploaded file

            'Let us recover only the file name from its fully qualified path at client 

            Dim strFileName As String
            strFileName = MyFile.PostedFile.FileName
            Dim c As String = CStr(DistributorID) & "." & split(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), ".")(1) ' The file name is the distid + the extension

            'Let us Save uploaded file to server 
            If LCase(Split(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), ".")(0)) = "" Then
                Span1.InnerHtml = "Please select a Photo.<br /><br />"
            End If

            If LCase(Split(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), ".")(1)) <> "jpg" Then
                Span1.InnerHtml = "Invalid file format."
            Else

                If MyFile.PostedFile.ContentLength < 250000 Then
                    MyFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DistImagePath") + c)
                    Span1.InnerHtml = "Your file imported sucessfully to the server.<br /><br />"
                Else
                    Span1.InnerHtml = "Your file is too large to import.<br /><br />"
                End If
            End If

        End Sub

    </script>
</head>
<body>      
    <span id="Span1" style="color:Red;" RunAt="Server" />                   
    <form method="Post" enctype="Multipart/Form-Data" RunAt="Server" class="stdform stdform2">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Select New Photo: <br />
        &nbsp;<input id="MyFile" type="File" runat="Server" size="40" /><br /><br />            
        <span style="padding-left:25px;">
            <button type="Submit" value="Import" OnServerclick="Upload_Click" RunAt="Server">Upload New Photo</button>
        </span>
    </form>
</body>
```

If no file is selected and the Upload New Photo button is pressed, I get a 
"Index was outside the bounds of the array." error

How can I fix this page to not attempt to upload a photo if they haven't selected one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose everything in an IF as so:

```
IF MyFile.PostedFile.ContentLength>0 Then 'User selected a file

   'All your code here
Else
    Span1.InnerHtml = "Your did not select a file.<br /><br />"
End IF
```

Full code:

```
 Sub Upload_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    IF MyFile.PostedFile.ContentLength>0  Then   
        Dim DistributorID As Integer
        DistributorID = request.QueryString("distID")

        ' Display properties of the uploaded file

        'Let us recover only the file name from its fully qualified path at client 

        Dim strFileName As String
        strFileName = MyFile.PostedFile.FileName
        Dim c As String = CStr(DistributorID) & "." & split(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), ".")(1) ' The file name is the distid + the extension

        'Let us Save uploaded file to server 
        If LCase(Split(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), ".")(0)) = "" Then
            Span1.InnerHtml = "Please select a Photo.<br /><br />"
        End If

        If LCase(Split(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName), ".")(1)) <> "jpg" Then
            Span1.InnerHtml = "Invalid file format."
        Else

            If MyFile.PostedFile.ContentLength < 250000 Then
                MyFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DistImagePath") + c)
                Span1.InnerHtml = "Your file imported sucessfully to the server.<br /><br />"
            Else
                Span1.InnerHtml = "Your file is too large to import.<br /><br />"
            End If
        End If
     Else
            Span1.InnerHtml = "Your did not select a file.<br /><br />"
     End IF

    End Sub
```

Comment: So would you suggest putting the IF statement around the Upload_Click Sub?

Answer (score 1):

```
If MyFile.PostedFile.ContentLength>0 
  ..
Else
   Span1.InnerHtml = "You have not specified a file."
End If
```

You can add this code before execute (If you want to execute upload file)

```
If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

    ......

Else
      Span1.InnerHtml = "You have not specified a file."
End If
```

Comment: No, he's not using the regular ASP.NET File Upload control... See the markup